# Iframe без скролбара

Tags: html

Есть фрейм с шириной 400 px и высотой 300 px. В него я загружаю музыку с фтп. Когда высота превышает 300 px, появляется скролбар. Можно ли этого избежать? Либо как-нить стилями поменять внешний вид скрола этого, а-то банально выглядит

Answer (score 1):

установите атрибут scrolling в no:

```
<iframe scrolling="no">...</iframe>
```

или

- http://www.tigir.com/css_scrollbar.htm
- http://www.siteedit.ru/scroll

want more? google it - ["изменить цвет scrollbar html"](http://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=bpvtybnm+wdtn+scrollbar+html#hl=ru&newwindow=1&sa=X&ei=lq8vTtOxKseLhQfbq8wn&ved=0CBYQBSgA&q=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82+scrollbar+html&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c0287908ed91e331&biw=1280&bih=886)